# PHP if (isset($_POST[''])) +Jquery send in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I would like to send a form so I don't get page refresh when I send a form.
Now when I press submit button I'm running this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send_this_message']) == 'yes')
    {
       echo "yes this is just example and working";
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="send_this_message" value="yes">
</form>Now how can send this form but without page refresh with jquery. I have seen several examples but they are all calling external files.. Something like this.
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "send.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == "done") {
                    alert("Form submitted successfully!");
                } else {
                    alert("Form submission failed!");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```

This code above is not working for me. I mean I need to somehow execute that isset when pressing on button.

Comment: The actual form and the jQuery code has nothing to do with one another. None of the selectors match, and is send.php even the same file ?

Comment: He just posted it as an example he found which not helped him.

Comment: It's a bad example, and it will never work. Also, to prevent the default form submit, use return false or preventDefault

Comment: Hi, This jquery code is just example which doesnt have anything to do with the php code above. Why i included it just to show what i dont wanna use. That means i don't want to use external file like that send.php..

Comment: "Why i included it just to show what i dont wanna use."  Doesn't then make any sense

Comment: @A.Wolff - What he doesn't want to use, is exactly what he has to use, so someone is clearly confused.

Comment: @adeneo i didn't see commented part in HTML code, if we can call it a commented part...

Comment: @A.Wolff - neither did I, it's hard to spot when someone adds the question inside the code.

Comment: @Mensur so where do you want to send FORM if it is not to a server side script? Couldn't you improve your question to make it understandable?! EDIT: and then i saw the title, "send it to the same page" Looks like i cannot get your logic behind it

Comment: In first place, you shouldn't send FORM but instead reset it and use datas values on same page. Isn't it a XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

As you want to send data without  page refresh, use Ajax to send the data from to your php file: (as example)

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'post.php',   // here your php file to do something with postdata
                data: $('form').serialize(), // here you set the data to send to php file
                success: function (data) {
                  alert('form was submitted');
                }
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });
          });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand very well your question
However you need to set a value for your attribut action in

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
```

for exemple

```
<form method="POST" action="responseForm.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting

```
$("#send")
```

it does not exist 
add the id to the button

```
<input id="send" type="submit" name="send_this_message" value="yes">
```

also you need to use `preventDefault()` for stopping the propagation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is called script.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send_this_message']) == 'yes')
{
   // do stuff
   echo "done"; // as confirmation for jQuery, see below
   die(); // no output the form because ajax function isn't interested in it
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <input type="submit" name="send_this_message" value="yes">
</form>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from being submitted normally
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "script.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == "done") {
                    alert("stuff done");
                } else {
                    alert("isset wasn't true");
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("server returned a 500 error or something");
            }
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```